# Loop in pygame - it never continues but keeps looping; what am I missing

Tags: python, pygame

UPDATED: added full script - when starting up the script, go to play and then start. It will run the questionnaire, but won't update as you see (well quickly, and then it resets; probably due to the loop it is in).

So, first of all: hi guys. I try to run a simple questionnaire in pygame. So far, things look okay. However, I run into a problem that I am not able to solve up till this point. I try to run a function (def_quiz) in a pygame window, but when I put this function below the 'while True' in the play_function it continues looping (logically). I tried to paste it somewhere else, e.g. above the 'while True' statement, but then my buttons are not working anymore. What do I miss? How can I solve my problem? I just simply want to play all the questions in the quiz function once.

```
# Import pygame and libraries
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randrange
import os
import pygame

# Import pygameMenu
import pygameMenu
from pygameMenu.locals import *

ABOUT = ['Game version: 2.0',
         'Author: Mandy Koopman',
         PYGAMEMENU_TEXT_NEWLINE,
         'Email: mn.koopman@st.hanze.nl']
COLOR_BACKGROUND = (200, 200, 200)
COLOR_BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
COLOR_WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
FPS = 60.0
MENU_BACKGROUND_COLOR = (228, 55, 36)
WINDOW_SIZE = (1280, 720)
display_width = 1280
display_height = 720

red   = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)
black = (0,0,0)

bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)

question_prompts = [
             "What color are apples?",
             "What color are bananas?"
             "How old are you",
        ]

answer_prompts = [("Antwoord A", "Antwoord B", "Antwoord C"), ("Antwoord A", "Antwoord B", "Antwoord C"),["a", "b", "c"]]

score_prompts = [(1,2,3),(1,2,3),[1,2,3]]
lijst = (0,1,2)


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Init pygame
pygame.init()
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'

# Create pygame screen and objects
surface = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
style = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption('Health Aware Game V2.0')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
dt = 1 / FPS

# Global variables
game_topic = ['SPORTS']


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

def change_difficulty(d):
    """
    Change difficulty of the game.

    :return: 
    """
    print ('Selected difficulty: {0}'.format(d))
    game_topic[0] = d


def random_color():
    """
    Return random color.

    :return: Color tuple
    """
    return randrange(0, 255), randrange(0, 255), randrange(0, 255)

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1:
            return True
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, ic,(x,y,w,h))


    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("arial",30)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    surface.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def update():
    for i in range(len(question_prompts)):
        count = i
        if i <= len(question_prompts):
            quiz(count)
        if i == len(question_prompts):
            print ("end")
        return count

def quiz(count):
    events = pygame.event.get()
    style.fill(pygame.Color("red"))
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',40)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(question_prompts[count], largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/3))
    style.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    if button("Antwoord A",150,450,200,100,green,bright_green) == True:
        print ("A")
        count +=1
    elif button("Antwoord B",550,450,200,100,red,bright_red) == True:
        print ("B")
        count +=1
    elif button("Antwoord C",950,450,200,100,red,bright_red) == True:
        print ("C")
        count +=1

def play_function(game_topic, font):
    """
    Main game function

    :param difficulty: Difficulty of the game
    :param font: Pygame font
    :return: None
    """
    #game_topic = game_topic[0]
    #assert isinstance(game_topic, str)

    #if game_topic == 'SPORTS':
    #     f = font.render('Playing as normie', 1, COLOR_WHITE)
    #elif game_topic == 'FOOD':
    #    f = font.render('Playing as normie', 1, COLOR_WHITE)
    #elif game_topic == 'SLEEP':
    #    f = font.render('Playing as god', 1, COLOR_WHITE)
    #else:
    #    raise Exception('Unknown difficulty {0}'.format(game_topic))

    # Draw random color and text
    #bg_color = random_color()
    #f_width = f.get_size()[0]

    # Reset main menu and disable
    # You also can set another menu, like a 'pause menu', or just use the same
    # main_menu as the menu that will check all your input.

    main_menu.disable()
    main_menu.reset(1)



    while True:

        # Clock tick
        clock.tick(60)

        # Application events


        update()
        playevents = pygame.event.get()



        for e in playevents:
            if e.type == QUIT:
                exit()
            elif e.type == KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    if main_menu.is_disabled():
                        main_menu.enable()

                        # Quit this function, then skip to loop of main-menu on line 197
                        return

        # Pass events to main_menu
        main_menu.mainloop(playevents)

        # Continue playing
        #surface.fill(bg_color)
        #surface.blit(f, ((WINDOW_SIZE[0] - f_width) / 2, WINDOW_SIZE[1] / 2))

        clock.tick(15)
        pygame.display.flip()



def main_background():
    """
    Function used by menus, draw on background while menu is active.

    :return: None
    """
    surface.fill(COLOR_BACKGROUND)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# PLAY MENU
play_menu = pygameMenu.Menu(surface,
                            bgfun=main_background,
                            color_selected=COLOR_WHITE,
                            font=pygameMenu.fonts.FONT_BEBAS,
                            font_color=COLOR_BLACK,
                            font_size=30,
                            menu_alpha=100,
                            menu_color=MENU_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                            menu_height=int(WINDOW_SIZE[1] * 0.8),
                            menu_width=int(WINDOW_SIZE[0] * 0.8),
                            onclose=PYGAME_MENU_DISABLE_CLOSE,
                            option_shadow=False,
                            title='Play menu',
                            window_height=WINDOW_SIZE[1],
                            window_width=WINDOW_SIZE[0]
                            )
# When pressing return -> play(DIFFICULTY[0], font)
play_menu.add_option('Start', play_function, game_topic,
                     pygame.font.Font(pygameMenu.fonts.FONT_FRANCHISE, 30))
play_menu.add_selector('Select game topic', [('Movement & Sports', 'SPORTS'),
                                             ('Food & Health', 'FOOD'),
                                             ('Sleep & Rest', 'SLEEP'),
                                             ('Other games', 'GAMES')],
                       onreturn=None,
                       onchange=change_difficulty)
play_menu.add_option('Return to main menu', PYGAME_MENU_BACK)

#highscores
high_menu = pygameMenu.Menu(surface,
                            bgfun=main_background,
                            color_selected=COLOR_WHITE,
                            font=pygameMenu.fonts.FONT_BEBAS,
                            font_color=COLOR_BLACK,
                            font_size=30,
                            menu_alpha=100,
                            menu_color=MENU_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                            menu_height=int(WINDOW_SIZE[1] * 0.8),
                            menu_width=int(WINDOW_SIZE[0] * 0.8),
                            onclose=PYGAME_MENU_DISABLE_CLOSE,
                            option_shadow=False,
                            title='Highscores',
                            window_height=WINDOW_SIZE[1],
                            window_width=WINDOW_SIZE[0]
                            )
# When pressing return -> play(DIFFICULTY[0], font)

high_menu.add_selector('Select highscores', [('Movement & Sports', 'SPORTS'),
                                             ('Food & Health', 'FOOD'),
                                             ('Sleep & Rest', 'SLEEP'),
                                             ('Other games', 'GAMES')],
                       onreturn=None,
                       onchange=change_difficulty)
high_menu.add_option('Start', play_function, game_topic,
                     pygame.font.Font(pygameMenu.fonts.FONT_FRANCHISE, 30))

high_menu.add_option('Return to main menu', PYGAME_MENU_BACK)


# ABOUT MENU
about_menu = pygameMenu.TextMenu(surface,
                                 bgfun=main_background,
                                 color_selected=COLOR_WHITE,
                                 font=pygameMenu.fonts.FONT_BEBAS,
                                 font_color=COLOR_BLACK,
                                 font_size_title=30,
                                 font_title=pygameMenu.fonts.FONT_8BIT,
                                 menu_color=MENU_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                                 menu_color_title=COLOR_WHITE,
                                 menu_height=int(WINDOW_SIZE[1] * 0.8),
                                 menu_width=int(WINDOW_SIZE[0] * 0.8),
                                 onclose=PYGAME_MENU_DISABLE_CLOSE,
                                 option_shadow=False,
                                 text_color=COLOR_BLACK,
                                 text_fontsize=20,
                                 title='About',
                                 window_height=WINDOW_SIZE[1],
                                 window_width=WINDOW_SIZE[0]
                                 )
for m in ABOUT:
    about_menu.add_line(m)
about_menu.add_line(PYGAMEMENU_TEXT_NEWLINE)
about_menu.add_option('Return to menu', PYGAME_MENU_BACK)

# MAIN MENU
main_menu = pygameMenu.Menu(surface,
                            bgfun=main_background,
                            color_selected=COLOR_WHITE,
                            font=pygameMenu.fonts.FONT_BEBAS,
                            font_color=COLOR_BLACK,
                            font_size=30,
                            menu_alpha=100,
                            menu_color=MENU_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                            menu_height=int(WINDOW_SIZE[1] * 0.8),
                            menu_width=int(WINDOW_SIZE[0] * 0.8),
                            onclose=PYGAME_MENU_DISABLE_CLOSE,
                            option_shadow=False,
                            title='Main menu',
                            window_height=WINDOW_SIZE[1],
                            window_width=WINDOW_SIZE[0]
                            )
main_menu.add_option('Play', play_menu)
main_menu.add_option('Highscores', high_menu)
main_menu.add_option('About', about_menu)
main_menu.add_option('Quit', PYGAME_MENU_EXIT)


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main loop
while True:

    # Tick
    clock.tick(60)

    # Application events
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()

    # Main menu
    main_menu.mainloop(events)

    # Flip surface
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. We should be able to just copy and paste your code and see the problem.

Comment: I added the full script.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to separate your buttons creation/updating to a different function that'll be called within the while loop because they won't be updated properly unless they're in there. Alternatively you could try converting your quiz() to a state machine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to split the updater and the button, but still I cannot get the script working. I can click on the buttons and they also give an output, but the questions still do not update (see new script above). What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that polls the event queue and gets the key/buttons pressed events:

```
events = pygame.event.get()
```

In the while loop you mention this line never gets ran and therefore events are not caught.

Furthermore you do not call `clock.tick()`

Therefore you must avoid a while in play_function (it is anti pattern to call both functions within the while there... it is correct they get called only in the main loop, so leave both where they are now). Assign a state variable and turn `play_function` into a function performing only one iteration of the loop, going back to the main loop where you can call the `pygame.event.get()` again and let the main loop perform all the looping. With a state (you define), `play_function` will be called again by the main loop and check if this is the first execution of play_function or not, so to execute or not the lines before the "current while". Or better yet, divide the `play_function`, e.g. `play_init` and `play_main`, in 2 and handle with a single state if to call the `play_init` or skip to `play_main`.

Example:

```
# Probably globals or better in a Class.
initialized = False
game_on = False

def play_function(playevents, game_topic, font):
    game_on = True;

def play_init():
    main_menu.disable()
    main_menu.reset(1)
    initialized = True

def play_action(playevents, game_topic, font):
    # skipping comments
    # add your stuff here

    update()

    for e in playevents:
        if e.type == KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                if main_menu.is_disabled():
                    main_menu.enable()
                    game_on = False
                    initialized = False
                    return

    # Continue playing
    #surface.fill(bg_color)
    #surface.blit(f, ((WINDOW_SIZE[0] - f_width) / 2, WINDOW_SIZE[1] / 2))

# Main loop
while True:

    # Tick
    clock.tick(60 if (game_on == False) else 15)

    # Application events
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()

    if game_on == True:
        if initialized == False:
            play_init()
        # this will be called every loop. this is what I am saying.
        play_action(events, game_topic, font) # expose args here
    else:
        # Main menu
        main_menu.mainloop(events)

    # Flip surface
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: I've been trying for a while no (see also updated code above) - but I don't think I am experienced enough at this point to solve the problem. How do I update in the main? Can you give me an example or a start of the solution maybe?

Comment: @Mandy I added a sample. Might not be 100% accurate and work, but it will illustrate how to use the main loop to loop the game even when  game is on.